# This has bugged me forever. The meaning of "particularly" is unclear

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, vocabulary

Example:

> Lee Kuan Yew once said, in Asian culture, particularly the Chinese,
> is always to wait for somebody to say it, and if anything goes wrong,
> pretend you've never agreed with it.

Are the rest of the Asians like this, just to a less degree, or is it unstated (same as "to be specific")?!

Because from the dictionaries, I think both are possible. But that puts every sentence with that word unclear!!

Comment: Your example is presumably made-up.  It doesn't quite make sense currently.  We'd say something more like "Lee Kuan Yew once said that in Asian culture, particularly Chinese culture, the tendency is always to wait for somebody else to suggest something, and if anything goes wrong, pretend you never agreed with it".  (Currently, you have no subject for the verb "is".)

Answer (score 2):

“particularly the Chinese” means to a greater degree for that subgroup, but it also applies to other “Asian culture” to a lesser degree.

Comment: Thank you. //to fulfill minimum comment length

Answer (score 1):

"Particularly" means "especially".  When we say "Asian culture, particularly Chinese culture", "Asian culture, especially Chinese culture", or "Asian culture, in particular Chinese culture", our statement applies to Asian culture generally but it applies even more strongly to Chinese culture.

Lexico has three definitions of "particularly":

- To a higher degree than is usual or average.
- Used to single out a subject to which a statement is especially applicable.
- So as to give special emphasis to a point; specifically.

Even where "particularly" means "specifically", "solely" is rarely if ever the correct interpretation, as shown by Lexico's [examples](https://www.lexico.com/definition/particularly):

- '*he particularly asked that I should help you*’: The suggestion is that the speaker has been given a range of requests, but the need to help the addressee was given particular emphasis.
- ‘*We particularly need to see the principal cast, especially the Lords of the North.*’: The suggestion is that the speaker would quite like to see the whole cast (*or* that the speaker has a range of needs), but that the speaker especially wishes to see the principal cast and even more so the Lords of the North.
- ‘*Pharmacies sell special camouflage make up, made particularly for covering up scars.*’: The camouflage may have been designed or manufactured specifically for that purpose but it isn't its sole use.
- ‘*I think the show will surprise a lot of people and that, particularly, Chris will.*’ Chris is the most surprising element of the show, but the show as a whole is also surprising.
- ‘*A notable feature of unemployment is that it particularly affects young people.*’ - It affects people in general, but it especially affects young people (and perhaps in particular ways).

*Caveat*.  I am confident that the correct interpretation of "Asian, particularly Chinese" is that the statement applies to both (but especially Chinese).  That said, if someone is speaking off the cuff and isn't an expert in the field, "Asian, particularly Chinese" could be their way of correcting themselves mid-sentence.  Perhaps they say "Asian" but then realise they're not quite sure whether this is true of Asian culture generally, and then they add "particularly Chinese".

Comment: Yes, no subject for "is", I know. Not important, but since you brought it up, it's here at 16:49.  https://youtu.be/YEcIsRo-m0A?t=1009      I'll think about your reply on the topic and reply later. Thank you for your big effort.

Comment: Thank you very much for your rigorous reply. My conclusion is yes, it mostly means "especially". 1. You as a native speaker should know this. 2. These example sentences indeed show that meaning. 3. In that 2rd meaning,  before it says "specifically", it says "So as to give special emphasis to a point".       
....................
  I really like your caveat - people does use it this way, although not rigorous I think.